# How To Use HTTPS on a Java webhook listener (Spark)

Tags: java, apache-spark, https, stripe-payments

I have had a webhook listener in my Java program for a while now, and it works like it's supposed to when you send a webhook to the listener's URL. Now I need to make the URL HTTPS, but I don't know if this is a problem that I need to fix in my Java code or my Apache webserver. I have a valid trusted certificate, but whenever I try to send a webhook through Stripe, it only says TLS error and returns nothing. I think it is because the ports of the listeners aren't using SSL, but I don't know how to fix that. If I add the port to virtual hosts in Apache to use HTTPS for the port, then Java can't listen on it because it will already be in use. This is my class for the listener. Do I need to add some code for it to listen through HTTPS?
An example URL for the listener (that works) would be http://verifus.ddns.net:4568/webhook. When HTTPS is there, it doesn't work at all.

```
import com.stripe.Stripe;
import com.stripe.model.*;
import com.stripe.net.ApiResource;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.core.entities.Role;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.simplejavamail.email.Email;
import org.simplejavamail.email.EmailBuilder;
import org.simplejavamail.mailer.MailerBuilder;
import us.verif.bot.Config;
import us.verif.bot.sql.StripeSql;

import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.EventListener;
import java.util.Random;

import static spark.Spark.port;
import static spark.Spark.post;

public class StripeWebhook implements EventListener {

    static final private String ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    final private Random rng = new SecureRandom();
    private JDA jda;


    public StripeWebhook(JDA jda) {
        this.jda = jda;
    }

    public void startListener() {

        port(Integer.parseInt(Config.getStripeWebhookPort()));


        post("/webhook", (request, response) -> {
            Event event = ApiResource.GSON.fromJson(request.body(), Event.class);
//Just some event checkers onwards
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, you will need to serve your Webhook endpoint using https. It is required by Stripe unfortunately. This should be configured on your web server (e.g. apache server).

Comment: SSL is already there in my server but using different ports doesn’t work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your Apache server with your SSL certificetes. You can [read the docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html) or follow some [guides](https://geekflare.com/apache-setup-ssl-certificate/) and [how-tos](https://www.digicert.com/csr-ssl-installation/apache-openssl.htm) on the exact steps.

Comment: My web server is already configured with SSL. https://Verifus.ddns.net is there something else I need to configure because the SSL already works but not on different ports?

Comment: You'd have to have it configured to the port as well where you run your webhook.

Comment: That’s the problem, if I configure SSL on the port by adding Listen <port> and making a virtual host, then the Java program can’t listen to that port.